# How do you validate a textbox in Visual Basic 2013 so that only 3 digits appear?

Tags: validation, visual-studio-2013, calculator

Im making a calculator in visual basic that adds and subtracts. How can validate the text so that only 3 digts appear in the textbox?

Comment: Add relevant code... and be specific

Comment: Which library are you using? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Runtime? Win Forms?

Answer (score 0):

Match with a Regex such as `^\d{3}$`